# $_REQUEST issue on PHP after using PHP 5.5.3 (old version: 5.3.1)

Tags: php, request

```
line 55 - include('config-and-functions.php');
line 56 - $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
```

I'm getting this error: `Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 56` after using a new PHP version.

There is some modification on `$_REQUEST` at this new php version? (5.5.3 - XAMPP 1.8.3)

Comment: I am guessing that you always had this problem but just now you have error display on and you saw it. It's normal since you are checking in any way if that field exists.

Comment: When this page is being accessed, is action always being passed either as GET or POST parameter. If not, use isset($_REQUEST['action') to check if it exists or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of php.ini change. Basically what it tells is the $_REQUEST array is not having an index by the name 'action'. It suggests to always check for existence of an index before using it.

You can override this in php using

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

or you can change this in php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Comment: let me try it out. Hohow! that's working D:. So, like @mishu has said, I always had this problem but just now I'm getting the report? lol

Comment: Uhh, if what you're doing is hiding the warning, please don't. You should always have all warnings/errors enabled for development, and disable them for deployment. In the case, you should `isset($_REQUEST['action'])`.

Comment: The question was why suddenly error started getting into a code which was working. So I pointed out the changes in php.ini, and a quick workaround in php. The question had no info about production/development. I too believe that notice should not be turned on in development, but should be turned off only in production.

Comment: don't worry guys, everything is working great, the problem was just these messages but now it's all OK! Thanks!